# How to restart Activity with new data. (Advancing levels in a game)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on a drag and drop puzzle game and the Activity that displays the actual "game" part of the app is called GameView. I start my `GameView` Activity with this code from a button click in my LevelSelect Activty like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LevelSelect.this, GameView.class);
            int levelNum = position+1;
            intent.putExtra("com.detour.obstruction.LevelNumber", levelNum);
            startActivity(intent);
```

This causes GameView to open and find whichever level (depending on the pressed button's position in a `Gridview`) it needs and display it. Now when the level is solved, I want to move  to the next level without going back to the LevelSelect screen. Think Angry Birds if that helps you understand what I am trying to do. What is the easiest/best way to do this? Can I change the data in my intent by calling `putExtra()` again and incrementing the value for level number? How do I clear out my GameView activity and restart it with a new level so that it appears seemless to the user?

Comment: Why would you want to restart the game? Wouldn't it be okie just to set the variables and refreshing the view once a particular level completes?

Comment: I restart the entire activity because there are other things that need reset also, like a TextView displaying the number of moves. However, you're suggestion does work well also and I would be glad to upvote it if you were to post it as a full answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing from within your activity. Just call `finish()` before calling `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: is it alright to call startActivity(intent) inside the activity that it starts? I tried this and it seemed to work alright but only once. Then, I would have to go out of the app and come back to have it work again.

Comment: what problem is coming? I made sample application for starting activity form same activity it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I needed. My other problems were unrelated.